# Sqlalchemy write to

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

```
 data.to_sql(dta, name='ib_es_minutes', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

I am using the code above to write pandas data frame to mysql database. It is working fine except sometimes I am getting same row written twice. Bellow
there are two rows at 20170522  08:03:00 which is my index column. Is there a
way that sqlalchemy can check if the index column is the same as the one before and just ignore the entry to mysql database of the entire row?

```
'20170522  08:00:00', '2385.5', '2385.5', '2385.5', '2385.5', '8'
'20170522  08:01:00', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385.25', '1'
'20170522  08:02:00', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385', '2385', '69'
'20170522  08:03:00', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385.25', '7'
'20170522  08:03:00', '2385.25', '2385.25', '2385', '2385.25', '335'
'20170522  08:04:00', '2385', '2385.25', '2385', '2385.25', '30'
```

Comment: You are using `if_exists='append'` which means: if the table exists, insert data regardless of whether it is already in there or not. Perhaps 'replace' is the right mode for you. Do you also have the duplicates in your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have duplicates in your dataframe beforehand, the `to_sql` is probably not introducing them. Best to handle them explicitly before writing to the database. For example:

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'timestamp'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

In your sample, your two `08:03:00` rows have different values in the last column. So you have to choose (implicitly or explicitly) which row to keep when you encounter duplicate timestamps.

It also suggests you probably have some join/merge upstream of this code that's not doing exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Yes I have duplicates in my dataframe.

Comment: does this `drop_duplicates` code resolve them in a way that works for you? Replace `date` and `timestamp` with the names you have for those columns.

Comment: In my case it would be better if sqlalchemy can read mysql database and if it sees the duplicate in the first column then just not to write the duplicate row.

Comment: can I ask why in your case you'd prefer to write duplicate rows to your database before de-duping them?

Comment: I am using this code dta=mydata.iloc[-1:] to get the pandas dataframe last row. I am getting update every minute. If I disconnect and connect within this minute I got the duplicate entry in mysql databse. Otherwise it is working ok. So that is why I want some check if that date and time is already written in mysql databse.